# Domain objects for reading vs saving

Tags: domain-driven-design, persistence

Suppose an object that has like 100 properties, but to create a new object only a few pieces of information are needed.

We are using WCF, and I see the following options:

1) Use the same domain object for both saving and reading the data. Downside is that it may not be immediately intuitive what properties need to be populated in order to create a new object.

2) Create my WCF service call such that I just pass in each piece of information needed as a separate parameter. But what if there were 15 parameters required instead of just 3... or what if the object changes and then it's a hassle to have to update the WCF method signature.

3) Create a separate object with only the required properties for saving.

I can see that maybe any of these 3 could be a suitable answer depending on the specific scenario. Thoughts?

Comment: You are looking for [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Thoughts?"

My thought is you are correct, any of these 3 could be a suitable answer. Solution number 2 looks somewhat like the `Builder` pattern, and solution 3 maybe combined with 2 - create a WCF service which gets the needed information in form of a separate object (a DTO).

Besides that, if your domain object has 100 properties, it may be time to question the design of that object (if you are not completely bound to it for legacy reasons).

Comment: Doesn't actually have 100 properties, but there are a number of properties that come from related tables that should not be updated from this object. I thought about putting the related domain objects on this domain object, but I only need a few properties from them and it would be a waste to have to load the entire objects so I'm just putting the properties I need directly on the object in question. I'm doing exactly what you mentioned... just haven't had to do this in the past and wanted a sanity check that my solution wasn't crazy :)